# JS Event triggered every second, but do action inside once

Tags: javascript, json, timing

```
var StreamFlash = "";

function Refresh() {
    if (EVENTDATA.events[RefreshEventsCurrentID].data.StreamFlash) {
        if (StreamFlash == "") {
            $('td.playercontainer').html(EVENTDATA.events[RefreshEventsCurrentID].data.StreamFlash);
            StreamFlash = EVENTDATA.events[RefreshEventsCurrentID].data.StreamFlash;
        }
        if (StreamFlash != EVENTDATA.events[RefreshEventsCurrentID].data.StreamFlash) {
            console.log('Load');
            $('td.playercontainer').html(EVENTDATA.events[RefreshEventsCurrentID].data.StreamFlash);
            StreamFlash = EVENTDATA.events[RefreshEventsCurrentID].data.StreamFlash;
        }
    }
    setTimeout(Refresh, 1000);
}
```

The function Refresh(); is triggered every second, this checks the variable EVENTDATA (json)  for changes in the flash streamobject, when the streamobject is changed, it has to load it once, and not every second.

How do i get this right??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your code should work: testing whether `StreamFlash` is different from the new data in `EVENTDATA` should make it run only when the data is changed.

I'd simplify the code a little bit, but if it still doesn't work try to log the `StreamFlash` data in `EVENTDATA` to see if it does indeed change.

```
var StreamFlash = "";

function Refresh() {
    var remoteStreamFlash = EVENTDATA.events[RefreshEventsCurrentID].data.StreamFlash;
    if (remoteStreamFlash && StreamFlash != remoteStreamFlash) {
        $('td.playercontainer').html(remoteStreamFlash);
        StreamFlash = remoteStreamFlash;
    }
    setTimeout(Refresh, 1000);
}
```